# is my understanding of copying by value / copying by reference in C correct?

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Here's how I think a C code execution works:

There's a map of variables used in a given code block that contains pairs:

`identifier: <address in memory where the value of a given type is located (its first byte)>`

They are discarded when a block ends and memory is automatically freed (but memory that we allocated ourselves is not released).

Their values are always copied if assigned to other identifiers. For example, below we have a structure in `t1` that is assigned to `t2`. The values are copied and we now have two exact objects (`t2` stores a copy of `t1`). Changing one doesn't change the other. This is different from i.e. javascript where `t1 = t2` would always lead to `t1` and `t2` point to the same location in memory.

```
typedef struct _thing 
{ 
    char item;
    char item2;
} THING;

int main (void) {
  THING t1;
  t1.item = 'a';
  t1.item2 = 'b';
  THING t2 = t1;
  t2.item = 'c';
  if (t1.item == 'a') {
    printf("t1.item is a");
  }
}
```

Below, we have copied reference (memory location where a value starts) to `t1` in `t2`. Identifier `t2` is mapped to memory address where memory address to object stored in `t1` starts. `&t1 == t2` but `&t1 != &t2`;

```
int main (void) {
  THING t1;
  t1.item = 'a';
  t1.item2 = 'b';
  THING* t2 = &t1;
  t2->item = 'c';
  if (t1.item == 'c') {
    printf("item is c");
  }
}
```

Finally, the last example shows how to handle objects similarly to how they are treated in javascript where non-primitive objects are always passed by reference:

```
int main (void) {
  THING* t1;
  THING* t2;
  t1 = (THING *) malloc (sizeof(THING));
  t1->item = 'a';
  t1->item2 = 'b';
  t2 = t1;
  t2->item = 'c';
  if (t1->item == 'c') {
    printf("item is c");
  }
  free(t1);
}
```

Here we have to explicitly say that `t1` and `t2` store pointers (`*`). Also we have to use arrow notation (`->`) instead of dot notation (`.`) and allocate/free memory manually.

Is this correct?

Comment: The compiler might maintain such a map of "pairs" but they do not exist at runtime ("C code execution").

Comment: "By value" and "by reference" are usually referring to the passing of the function parameters. Which is not something any of your examples is doing.

Comment: In the first example `=` copies the entire `struct` contents. Then there are two `struct`s with the same content, until you change one of them, which does not change the other. You can't do that with an array. In the second example `=` creates a *pointer* to the first `struct`. There is only one `struct`, and whatever you to the `struct` is the same through the pointer. You can do that with an array too. The third example allocates memory, and the same applies: there is only one `struct`. In the first two cases the storage is automatic, in the third case it has to be `free`d.

Comment: @WeatherVane I can't clone an array because an array is virtually a pointer to a sequence of values, right?

Comment: I said "you can't do that with an array". Meaning you can't just equate an array to another, unlike what you can do with a `struct`. But you can assign a pointer and copy the pointer wherever you like with `=`. That does not copy any content.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh right, I cannot just assign one array to a different identifier. If I want to clone an array I need to iterate through and copy array values.

Comment: Or use bulk copy like `memcpy`.

Comment: @WeatherVane cool, thanks.

Comment: No, an array is not "virtually a pointer to a sequences of values". An array is a sequence of values.  You could point to it like you could point to any other variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Here's how I think a C code execution works:
>
> There's a map of variables used in a given code block that contains
>   pairs:

In an "as if" sense, perhaps.  Real-world C implementations do not have literal maps such as you describe.  In fact, variables' identifiers are not generally available at runtime at all.  They are resolved to addresses at compile and / or link time, before the program runs.

> They are discarded when a block ends and memory is automatically freed
>   (but memory that we allocated ourselves is not released).

Automatically-allocated objects' lifetimes end at the point where their identifiers go out of scope.  This may or may not have exactly the same meaning and implications as those you describe by the term "discarded".

> Their values are always copied if assigned to other identifiers.

Yes, assignment is a copy operation.  But in the context of this particular question, it is important to understand what the value is that is copied (assigned).  In particular, pointers are first-class objects in C, distinct from the objects, if any, to which they point.  Assigning a pointer value to a different pointer is an altogether different operation from assigning the value of one pointed-to object to the other pointed-to object.

> For example, below we have a structure in `t1` that is assigned to `t2`. The values are copied and we now have two exact objects (`t2` stores a copy of `t1`). Changing one doesn't change the other. This is different from i.e. javascript where `t1 = t2` would always lead to `t1` and `t2` point to the same location in memory.

Yes, in C, objects having structure type are directly accessible, and assigning to one modifies the object itself.  But note that such an assignment operation is shallow, in the sense that when any of the structure members are pointers, *the pointer* is copied, leaving that member an alias of the corresponding member of the original structure.

> Below, we have copied reference (memory location where a value starts) to `t1` in `t2`. [...]

I note at this point that C does not have "references".  It has *pointers*, whose values represent addresses.  This is a very similar concept, but not an identical one.

In any case, however, your understanding of the address-of operator, `&`, and of pointer assignment appears to be correct.

> Finally, the last example shows how to handle objects similarly to how they are treated in javascript where non-primitive objects are always passed by reference:

Your example shows a way to create a pointer to a structure object without declaring the object itself (and thereby having it allocated automatically and associated with its own identifier).  Note well, however, that although this is reminiscent of handling objects via references in Javascript, it has little to do with *pass by reference*, which is about calling functions / invoking methods.

C (unlike C++) does not have pass-by-reference.  C function calls are always pass-by-value, but the values passed can be pointers.  As I understand it, this is analogous to Javascript, which also has only pass by value (where the values passed can be references).

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, I really appreciate it. A reference is a memory address to a location where a value begins and a pointer is a data type that stores a reference, right?

Comment: No, @marzelin.  A pointer (in C) is an object whose value represents an address.  The usual meaning of a "reference" in language contexts where it is defined is, approximately, the address *of an object*.  The distinction is a bit subtle, but very important.

Comment: so there are no references in C and what `&` operator returns is an address. A reference in other languages is an address of an object (and in those languages there are generally no way (no use) to get address of non-objects). Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, @marzelin, with the caveat that some languages provide a special reference value (often named `null`, `nil`, or similar) that explicitly does not refer to any object.  C has a concept analogous to that, too, but more generally provides no inherent guarantee that the values of pointers necessarily point to objects (or functions, for function pointers).

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your time.